# How do I create a valueless Attribute on HtmlGenericControl

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am creating a new HtmlGenericControl in C#/ASP.net and need to create an attribute on the control with no value. This means no ="" after the attribute.

```
oHtmlGenericControl = new HtmlGenericControl("MyHtmlTag");
oHtmlGenericControl.Attributes.Add("MyFirstAttribute", "MyAttributeValue");
oHtmlGenericControl.Attributes.Add("MySecondAttribute", "");
```

Will produce something like this...

```
<MyHtmlTag MyFirstAttribute="MyAttributeValue" MySecondAttribute=""></MyHtmlTag >
```

And what I want is this...

```
<MyHtmlTag MyFirstAttribute="MyAttributeValue" MySecondAttribute></MyHtmlTag >
```

I've tried passing null instead of an emptry string but then the attribute does not appear at all.

I did the following *thinking* it was working at first...

```
oHtmlGenericControl = new HtmlGenericControl("MyHtmlTag");
oHtmlGenericControl.TagName = oHtmlGenericControl.TagName + " MySecondAttribute";
```

But it ended up giving me this...

```
<MyHtmlTag MySecondAttribute></MyHtmlTag MySecondAttribute>
```

**So, according to the comments, there may not be any "valueless" attributes in HTML. On closer inspection of the W3C standard the proper way to add the attribute I needed to add was  AttributeName="AttributeName". The AttributeName by itself is accepted and considered valid by most browsers though and given without a value in most online examples.**

```
oHtmlGenericControl.Attributes.Add("MyAttributeName", "MyAttributeName");
```

So the above example will work in my case (and possibly all similar cases), but doesn't exactly answer the question on if it is possible to add an attribute without a value using the HtmlGenericControl.

```
<MyHtmlTag MyAttributeName="MyAttributeName"></MyHtmlTag>
```

Comment: Why would you want that? There is really no valueless attributes in HTML. Most browser do accept them (like 'disabled' in input fields), but that is just their syntactic convention. Writing 'disabled="true"' is the correct way to write those attributes, as HTML is concerned.

Comment: @Joonas "checked" is one example

Comment: Yes, browsers will evaluate 'checked' correctly, even if it's not valid XHTML, but valid way to write it is checked='checked'.

Comment: I'm trying to hunt the reason WHY OP wants valueless attrbutes?

Comment: @Joonas actually, the only reason for checked='checked' is to support XHTML. It is a valueless attribute in HTML 4 and 5.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, i.e. 'checked' is a valid attribute in HTML4 and HTML5. 'checked="checked" is a valid attribute in HTML4 and HTML5 AND XHTML (and of course XML). So why not use format that is more supported?

Comment: @Joonas you are right. But I don't like to assume the "why", I like to answer the question. Maybe OP is experimenting with Web Components or something.

Comment: I think you are all on the right track. Looking back at the W3 spec, the proper way to add the attribute is indeed AttributeName="AttributeName". Every example I saw though just had the AttributeName by itself. I did try setting the Attribute to "True" and "False" but that didn't work.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes "If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name", so 'true' and 'false' are not valid. So my first comment had an error.

Answer (score 0):

First, investigate why you need an empty attribute. Maybe you have a valid reason, if so try this (untested):

```
var wr = new System.IO.StringWriter(new StringBuilder("MySecondAttribute"));
var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(wr);
oHtmlGenericControl.Attributes.AddAttributes(htw);
```

Comment: Worth a try. Did it add the ="", or just did it just fail?

Comment: It didn't error out, just didn't add the attribute at all.